# Compensating wage differentials for risk

Tags: microeconomics

**Question:**

The utility from daily income $(x)$ of an individual is given by $$U(x) = 100x - 0.5x^2$$ The only source of income is his earnings. Hence, $x = wl$ where $w = \text{wage}$ and $l = \text{labour hours}$. He has two job offers:

1. Job $1:$ $8$-hour day at wage $5$/hr
2. Job $2:$ Work hours are random - with a mean of $8$ hrs and [SD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of $6$ hrs. Wage $w_0$ is promised.

For what $w_0$ will the individual take up the second job?

**Book's solution:**

$\mathbb{E}[U(x_{\text{job}_1})] = 3200$ and $\mathbb{E}[U(x_{\text{job}_2})] = \mathbb{E}[100w_0h - 0.5 (w_0h)^2] = 800w_0 - 0.5 w_0^2 (36 + 64) = 800w_0 - 50w_0^2$

**My attempt:**

Utility from the first job is $U(8 \cdot 5) = 3200$ and the expected utility from the second job is $\mathbb{E}[U(w_0h)]$ where $h$ is a random variable with $\mu_h = 8, SD(h) = 6$. $h$ gives the number of labour hours worked for job $2$ on a particular day.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[U(w_0h)] &= 100w_0 \mathbb{E}[h] - 0.5w_0^2 E[h^2] \\
&= 100w_0 \mathbb{E}[h] - 0.5 w_0^2 (\text{Var}(h) + \mu_h^2) \\
&= 100w_0 \mathbb{E}[h] - 50 w_0^2 
\end{align}

The requires $w_0$ will be given by one that satisfies $100w_0 \mathbb{E}[h] - 50 w_0^2 \geq 3200$ (or in particular, equality, to achieve indifference).

**How do I proceed?**

I think the book's solution assumes $\mathbb{E}(h) = 8$ but that isn't necessarily true. The distribution isn't mentioned and that would assume something like the normal distribution.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't necessarily true that $\mathbb{E}(h)=8$?  The specification of Job 2 states a mean of 8 work hours.

Comment: Note from OP: $\mathbb{E}(h) = 8$. That solves the problem.